# convert from mysql php script to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, xml, pdo

I am actually new to PDO

Here I am trying to fetch data from mysql and show in xml.

I have done it using mysql, but I could not be able to done it using PDO.

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "root";
$database   = "my_db";

// replace by a real *.xsl file, e.g.
// $xslt_file = "exam.xsl";
$xslt_file  = FALSE; 
// If true, will output XML without XSLT

$raw        = TRUE; 

  $SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM `battery` order by waste asc";

$DB_link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_select_db($database, $DB_link) or die ("Could not find or access the database.");
$result = mysql_query ($SQL_query, $DB_link) or die ("Data not found. Your SQL query didn't work... ");

$left = "<";
$right = ">";

if ($xslt_file or $raw) {
  // we produce XML
  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  $XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
  if (!$raw) $XML .= "<?xml-stylesheet href=\"$xslt_file\" type=\"text/xsl\" ?>";
 }
 else {
   // we produce HTML. All XML tags are replaced by printable entities
   $XML = "Don't forget to create an XSLT file .... <p>";
   $XML .= "<pre>\n";
   $left = "&lt;";
   $right = "&gt;";
 }

// root node
  $XML .= $left . "result" . $right . "\n";
// rows
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {    
  $XML .= "\t" . $left. "row" . $right . "\n";  // creates either "<row>" or "&lt;row&gt;"
  $i = 0;
  // cells
  foreach ($row as $cell) {
    // Escaping illegal characters
    $cell = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $cell);
    $col_name = mysql_field_name($result,$i);
    // creates the "<tag>contents</tag>" representing the column, either as XML or for display in HTML
    $XML .= "\t\t" . $left . $col_name . $right . $cell . $left . "/" . $col_name . $right ."\n";
    $i++;
  }
  $XML .= "\t" . $left. "/row" . $right . "\n";
 }

  $XML .= $left . "/result" . $right . "\n";

echo $XML;
if (!$xslt_file && !$raw) echo "</pre>";

?>
```

I am trying a lot, but i could not be able to done it using PDO
Please i need some help.
Any Help will be appreciated.

My PDO code that i tried is

```
  <?php
    $dbtype     = "mysql";
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "my_db";
    $dbuser     = "root";
    $dbpass     = "root";

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$xslt_file  = FALSE; 

$raw        = TRUE; 

  $SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM `battery` order by waste asc";
  $result = $conn->query($SQL_query);

$left = "<";
$right = ">";

if ($xslt_file or $raw) {

  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  $XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
  if (!$raw) $XML .= "<?xml-stylesheet href=\"$xslt_file\" type=\"text/xsl\" ?>";
 }
 else {

   $XML = "Don't forget to create an XSLT file .... <p>";
   $XML .= "<pre>\n";
   $left = "&lt;";
   $right = "&gt;";
 }


  $XML .= $left . "result" . $right . "\n";

  while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
  $XML .= "\t" . $left. "row" . $right . "\n";  // creates either "<row>" or "&lt;row&gt;"
  $i = 0;
  // cells
  foreach ($row as $cell) {
    // Escaping illegal characters
    $cell = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cell);
    $cell = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $cell);

     $col_name = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    // creates the "<tag>contents</tag>" representing the column, either as XML or for display in HTML
    $XML .= "\t\t" . $left . $col_name . $right . $cell . $left . "/" . $col_name . $right ."\n";
    $i++;
  }
  $XML .= "\t" . $left. "/row" . $right . "\n";
 }

  $XML .= $left . "/result" . $right . "\n";

echo $XML;
if (!$xslt_file && !$raw) echo "</pre>";

?>
```

But it shows nothing

Comment: Where is `PDO` code, this is all `mysql` code.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: <?php
   while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
   $XML .= "\t" . $left. "row" . $right . "\n";  // creates either "<row>" or "&lt;row&gt;"
   $i = 0;
   // cells
   foreach ($row as $cell) {
     // Escaping illegal characters
     $cell = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $cell);
     $cell = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cell);
     $cell = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cell);
     $cell = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $cell);

      $col_name = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
 ?>

Comment: paste this code in your question not in comment.

Comment: And how are you creating `$result` in your PDO code...?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to fetch column names is

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE tablename");
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

however as you are fetching an assoc you could just change your foreach loop to this:

```
foreach ($row as $col_name => $cell) {
```

There may be other issues, have you tried using print_r on the result of each PDO function call to check at what point it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

you connect to the database like this :

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "testcreate";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "mysql";

try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf-8', ''.$dbuser.'', ''.$dbpass.'');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo 'Error : <br>' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

> **PS: You dont need the try and the catch, but we used to get the error and handle it in a nice way as we want to**

and next we query like this :

```
 $db->query(SELECT * FROM node WHERE node_name='$nodename'");
```

and we fetch it like this :

```
 $query = $db->query(SELECT * FROM node WHERE node_name='$nodename'");
 $row   = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

and now you use `$row->name` for example

here is more about PDO::FETCH

> - **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC**: returns an array indexed by column name as returned    in your result set
> - **PDO::FETCH_BOTH** (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result    set
> - **PDO::FETCH_BOUND**: returns TRUE and assigns the values of the columns in your result set to the PHP variables to which they were
>     bound with the PDOStatement::bindColumn() method
> - **PDO::FETCH_CLASS**: returns a new instance of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the
>     class. If fetch_style includes PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g.
>     **PDO::FETCH_CLASS** | **PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE)** then the name of the class
>     is determined from a value of the first column.
> - **PDO::FETCH_INTO**: updates an existing instance of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in
>     the class
> - **PDO::FETCH_LAZY**: combines PDO::FETCH_BOTH and PDO::FETCH_OBJ, creating the object variable names as they are accessed
> - **PDO::FETCH_NUM**: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0
> - **PDO::FETCH_OBJ**: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set

Comment: Dude. Do not spam your copy-pasted answer for the every question you can find.